# How to find all files from mixed of hard and symbolic folders?

Tags: bash

I have a directory that contains sub directories with mixed of hard folders or symbolic folders. I would like to find all `*fastq.gz` files among these folders. I have tried

```
find -H ./ -maxdepth 2 -name '*fastq.gz'
```

But it returns nothing.

Comment: I have removed the phrase in case of confusion.

Comment: 1) What is an example of the path of an existing file that you think should match but which doesn't? (eg. `./dir1/file.fastq.gz`) 2) Why are you using `-H` if you want to traverse symlinks?

Comment: `find` does not chase symlinks because then it could very easily get stuck in an endless loop. You'll probably want to `find` symbolic links separately and then traverse them.